# Resize image based on X and Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, gatsby, contentful

I have a Gatsby application using the CMS Contentful. I have implemented Image Focal Point on Contentful which returns x and y coordinates for image cropping. I have tried using HTML Canvas to resize the image based on the coordinates from Image Focal Point but with no luck.

Here is what I have tried:

```
const resizeImage = (url, width, height, x, y, callback) => {

  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
  const imageObj = new Image()

  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height
  imageObj.src = url
  imageObj.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous")

  imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height, x, y, width, height)
    callback(canvas.toDataURL())
  }
  return imageObj.src
}
```

I pass in the url for the image, the width and height of said image, the x and y coordinates from Image Focal Point and a callback:

```
resizeImage("my-image.png", 1000, 500, 300, 600, (url) => {url})
```

This returns the same src url as I inputted and does not crop the image to the desired xy coordinates. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may have had security issues, specifically this: for security reasons, your local drive is declared as "other domain" and it will stain the canvas. and for this reason his image was not cropped. I ran into this problem with an image of a server while replicating your code, so be careful.

I generated a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-platform-jiodb?file=/src/index.js) with your code, let me know if you want to cut the image in this way

```
const resizeImage = (url, width, height, x, y, callback) => {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const imageObj = new Image();
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  imageObj.src = url;
  imageObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; //WARNING!
  imageObj.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
    const url = canvas.toDataURL();
    callback(url);
  };
};
```